# Subview receiving touches outside its frame in parent view

Tags: ios, uiview, parent-child, subview

I can't figure out why this is happening, but I have a subclass of UIView that is added to my view controller's view.

```
productView = [[SKUProductView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,768, 700, 550)];
[self.view addSubview:productView];
```

The view starts offscreen and will animate onscreen on a pan gesture event.While the view is offscreen, it is receiving touch events outside its own frame. I have developed a work around by overriding the hitTest method in the subview to return a hitTest call to the superview if the touch event is outside its frame.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Test to determine if view is offscreen or if touch is outside its frame
    if (self.frame.origin.y >= 768 || point.x > self.frame.size.width)
    {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
    else if (point.y < kSKU_SCROLLVIEW_Y_OFFSET)
    {
        return [_productTabBar hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }

    return _productScrollView;
```

}

but I'm wondering why would my subview receive touch events outside its own frame in the first place?

Comment: Are you setting up the UIPanGesture recogniser in the storyboard or in code? Could you post the code if you do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using

```
CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
```

to determine if the touch point is inside the frame of view ?

To be sure, print on console the view frame with `NSStringFromCGRect()` function so you can understand what's happening.